# How to stub a void returning method in C++ with GoogleMock

Tags: c++, googlemock

In my project I write some tests using C++, GoogleTest and GoogleMock.

In these tests I want to test some clue code and I have created a mock class for the class which is processed by this clue code.

The mock class has these methods:

```
struct SomeData_t
{
    int field_0;
    int field_1;
};

class MyMockClass : public MyProcessingInterface
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD1( StartBuffer, void( const unsigned int type));
    MOCK_METHOD1( AddData, int( const SomeData_t &data));
};
```

In one test case I want to test just `AddData` and stub `StartBuffer`.

How can I stub `StartBuffer` and suppress the "Uninteresting mock function call" warnings from GoogleMock?

Comment: IIRC _"Uninteresting mock function call"_ is issued for non expected function calls. If you use a `nice_mock` these should be suppressed.

Comment: It's explained in detail here: https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CookBook.md

Comment: Well, my question is actually not a duplicate of the referred one, but 'nice_mock' will do the trick. Thanks.

Comment: The dupe's at least explains why the _"Uninteresting mock function call"_ is issued. Since I've noticed that `nice_mock`  wasn't mentioned there, I have added the link to the documentation.